# Broadcast Receiver inside Activty not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am working on an application that display the messages , for that i am using BroadcastReceiver inside my activity and i am trying to refresh the listview inside onReceive method , but onReceive is not getting call some how please help me with this.

```
public class MessageActivity extends BaseActivity {


    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Extract data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside Reciver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getSMSCursorCount();
            loadInitialMessages();
          }
        };
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.messageinbox);
}

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        intentFilter.setPriority(1000);
        registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
            Log.d("This is onResume method ","<<<<<<<<< onResume <<<<<<<<<");
            try {
                getSMSCursorCount();
                loadInitialMessages();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if (e.getMessage().contains("Receiver not registered")) {
                // Ignore this exception. This is exactly what is desired
                Log.w(TAG,"Tried to unregister the reciver when it's not registered");
            } else {
                // unexpected, re-throw
                throw e;
            }
        }
         Log.d("This is onPause method ","<<<<<<<<< onPause <<<<<<<<<");
    }
```

Comment: have you add permission for telephoney??

Comment: Yes i have included all the necessary permissions. Problem is with broadcast receiver please update me on that if you find any mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write separate broadcast receiver class by extending BroadcastReceiver and declare it in your manifest file with intentfilter. Override the onReceive method and call your activity there.In oncreate of activity refresh yor listview if the intent is from broadcast receiver.

```
 public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("inside message receiver... ");

           Intent popupintent = new Intent(context,ShowNotificationDialog.class);
            popupintent.putExtra("from", "broadcast");
            context.startActivity(popupintent);  



    }



public class ShowNotificationDialog extends Activity
        {

         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Intent i = getIntent();
      String fromString = i.getStringExtra("from");
      if(from != null)
       {
       if(from.equals("from"))

       // refresh your listview

       }

    }
}
```

In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MessageReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="broadcast action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: -Madhu we can do it this way also, i you know anything about the current method let me know

Comment: What you are suggesting is not necessary .

Comment: @hemant else you can try by registering your broadcast receiver in oncreate method

Comment: – Madhu i have registered it inside onResume

Comment: @hemant i have faced the same problem some days ago and i solved it in that way which i have suggested in above answer.